# Phone Emulator also opens on debugging Windows universal application

Tags: windows-phone-8, win-universal-app

i have a windows 8.1 universal application.

Now i want to debug the Windows application in my simulator.
Whenever i debug the windows application in my simulator, it also opens the phone emulator. Emulator deployment fails but simulator works fine.

Is it a correct behaviour ?

cheers,
Saurav

Comment: You mean both the emulators are opening at the same time? Did you make the `Windows` project as the startup project?

Comment: Yes i made the Windows project as a startup pr

Comment: Did you try turning off the phone emulator through the `Hyper-V`?

Comment: Do i have to disable phone emulator manually ? shouldn't running simulator suffice that ?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on a solution -> select **Properties** then navigate to **Common properties** -> **Startup project** and make sure **Single startup project** option selected.

Comment: thanks Anthony for the comment...i have the single startup project option selected

Answer (score 0):

I had to disable Hyper-V from Windows Featur
This link helps http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2014/03/11/step-by-step-enabling-hyper-v-for-use-on-windows-8-1.aspx